# Katalon Studio to upload more than one file to same input field

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

There is file input field on page, where should be attached more than one file at the same time.

I try to use [[WebUI] Upload File](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-upload-file.html#description), but it is unable to handle two files simultaneously.

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/validateFile/input_originalFile'), (d_directory.toString() + '\\') + file1, (d_directory.toString() + '\\') + file2)
```

Comment: Is simultaneous upload of two files necessary condition?

Comment: @MateMrše : Yes, all the two should be attached at the same time and sent to processing in a pair.

Answer (score 2):

```
file1 = "C:\\path\\file.extension";
file2 = "C:\\path\\file.extension";
multipleFiles = file1 + "\n" + file2;

WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('yourTestObject'), multipleFiles)
```

Hope this helps

also, this list might help you in the future

```
Escape Sequence Description
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
```

Comment: I get error message in this case: `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found`

Answer (score 1):

check whether input file type is= "file".

Comment: Yes, element looks like this: `<input type="file" name="originalFiles" id="originalFiles" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: You can’t select multiple files at once I assume, This will help: https://forum.katalon.com/t/multiple-files-upload/8977/7

Comment: It doesn't happen simultaneously in this example. Here is a site as an example: https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation "Original file(s)" field can handle more than one file at the same time.

Comment: This should be added as a comment to the OP, not as an answer.

Comment: Since I do not have the privilege to comment